# Which one was the best approach to implementing Asynchronous service call in android

Tags: android

I would like to implement a service(Web service) call in my application.
I blocked here for a while. 
Previously I followed some of the below concepts.
like, AsyncTask class, Thread concepts and Handlers.

Recently I heard about the [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Based on by experience, retrofit was good with high performance.
But it's not that much of reliable.
Example:

```
   {
      "Tag1":"Tag Value",
      "TagArray":[    {"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}    ]
   }
```

POJO:

```
public class Data{
String key1,key2;

sterres...

getters..

}
```

If the response have some other tags that are no need and the inside data only we need in our app i,e. "TagArray".
I need the handle only this response.

In such type of case this retrofit was failed.

Is there any other libraries or any other components to implement service calls in android with high performance are existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your POJOs' or Beans' fields `@Optional`. This option comes from GSON that used in Retrofit as default.

**EDIT :**

```
public class ExamplePojo implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("TagArray")
public ArrayList<Keys> TagArray;

public ExamplePojo() {
    TagArray = new ArrayList<>();
}

    public static class Keys{
       @SerializedName("key1")
       public String key1;

       @SerializedName("key2")
       public String key2;
    }
}
```

The attributes which you ignore shouldnt be added on POJO class or as mention above, add optional annotation if it can be null.

Comment: Thanks Emre Akturk for giving response, I have POJO for Data inside the "TagArray" I need the List of my POJO.  Is there any way of decleration to hold only the list for the above response?

Comment: I already mentioned above, that is I don't want to include unnecessary code in my app. I don't want to include "TagArray" key anymore, Just I need its data and in the form list. (List<Data> listData;) 
How we going to implement in normal asynch task class.

Comment: Same exactly how we going to implement in normal asynch task class.

We need only those two keys "key1, key2" in our app. So we mentioned in pojo. And one more thing that, No way to change the service response.